# How to compare parameter passed through POST method with Django rest framework Model and generate custom response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am designing Basic Django rest framework based application, i need to compare external parameters passed through ***POST*** method in Postman with Coupon code in database and generate custom response like 'This code is redeemed/validate." or " This is invalid coupon/code."

Here is my Model.py file :

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField()
    discount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

here is my views.py file:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Coupon
from .serializers import CouponSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class CouponViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Coupon.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CouponSerializer


    @api_view(['POST'])
    def coupon_redeem(request):
        if request.method =='POST':
            serializer = CouponSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

here is my Serializer.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Coupon


class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = '__all__'
```

Please help if possible, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IN Your post method u can filter the desired object like:

```
if serializer.is_valid():

    coup=Coupon.objects.filter(code=serializer.data['code'],active=True).exists()
    if(coup=="NULL"):
        return Response("This is invalid coupon/code",status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response("This is valid code",status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Hi i am getting error "coupon with this code already exists." i am not getting this response 'This is invalid coupon/code'

Comment: @AdityaAcharya i think u are saving the object too?? as duplicate entries will be there and you have unique=True in your models

Comment: @AdityaAcharya i think u are saving the object too?? as duplicate entries will be there and you have unique=True in your models

Comment: Yes but i just want to compare externally inserted parameter with code exist in database.

Comment: yes u do not have to save the serializer u just have to send your code in the body of your post hit via postman with the key 'code' and filter from your database that it exists if it do not exists the query results null.